# Lyx table: two equivalent columns

Tags: tables, lyx

I have a simple table with two columns, which should have an equivalent width.
I tried to set each column's width to 50% text width.
Rightclick -> More -> Settings -> Table Settings -> Width

Now, the columns have an equivalent width,but the table does not respect the text width.

I have another table, where I have set just one column to a width in cm and the other column is not set. In this table everything is fine. The second column adapt automatically, and the table does not overflow the text width.

In both cases, the tables are placed inside a standard float element.

What do I wrong in the first case?

Comment: Can you show code for table? I'm not expert for lyx, but features of tables had to be determined in LaTeX.

Comment: How much do they extend into the margin? Two columns of 50% texrtwidth will actually make a table slightly wider than textwidth, because there is some space before/between/after columns that is not accounted for.

Comment: Ok, when I set the width of each column to 47%, it looks fine. But I think this behavior is just plain stupid. It is probably the gap between, the border lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when LaTeX makes a table it inserts a space of length `\tabcolsep` at the start and end of each column. The specified width of a column comes in addition to this length. That's why when you have two columns of `0.5\textwidth`, the table is a bit wider (`4\tabcolsep`) than the text width.

There are ways around this, demonstrated in the LaTeX code below. The `tabularx` package and its `X` columns can be quite handy, but there is no support for it in the LyX GUI I believe, so you would have to write the table code by hand in an ERT.

To use the second alternative presented, calculating a length, add

```
p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
```

in the *LaTeX argument* box in the table settings in LyX (do it for each column, of course):

[image]

This won't let you use the other column settings, so if you want centered text in the cells, use

```
>{\centering}p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}
```

instead. You also need to go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\usepackage{array}
```

as that package is required for the `>{stuff}` syntax, but isn't loaded by default. (`>{stuff}` added before a column specifier, e.g. `p{1cm}`, inserts `stuff` at the start of each cell in that column.)

## Code example and output

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip} % just for example, sets zero parindent and some parskip
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
What you're doing:

X\dotfill X % illustrates textwidth

\begin{tabular}{| p{0.5\linewidth} | p{0.5\linewidth} |}
\hline
ABC & DEF \\
ABC & DEF \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

X\dotfill X

Removing space between columns (looks bad, don't do it):

X\dotfill X

\begin{tabular}{| @{} p{0.5\linewidth} @{} | @{}p{0.5\linewidth} @{}|}
\hline
ABC & DEF \\
ABC & DEF \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

X\dotfill X

Calculate suitable length:

X\dotfill X 

\begin{tabular}{| p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax} | p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax} |}
\hline
ABC & DEF \\
ABC & DEF \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

X\dotfill X

Using \texttt{tabularx} (not available via GUI in LyX):

X\dotfill X

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X |}
\hline
ABC & DEF \\
ABC & DEF \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}


X\dotfill X


Set the default column sep to zero with \verb|\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}| (I wouldn't do this):
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

X\dotfill X


\begin{tabular}{| p{0.5\linewidth} | p{0.5\linewidth} |}
\hline
ABC & DEF \\
ABC & DEF \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution works almost perfect, but when I use a Latex argument in Lyx, the column settings grey out, and the text is not centred anymore. Could you help me out with the centred statement?

Comment: @user59442 `>{\centering}p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}` and add `\usepackage{array}` in Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble.